# iPhone 4, High-Resolution Screen Support

Tags: ios4

It became High-Resolution Screen Support from iOS4.

I make the custom button with UIButton. 
It is prolonged in 640x960 and it is displayed. 
With this, it is not significant.

Isn't there method that makes 640x960 a standard and displays?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I make XIB file. The resolution of XIB is not revokable in 320x480. The resolution wants to make me XIB of 640x960 for iPhone4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@2x naming :**

This will holds good for images in application bundle, How abou the image that i am downloading from server?

I am downloading the image as NSData and initialize the UIImage with the data. I found the image is blurred in iPhone 4 Simulator.

Can the naming convention in image url will do the stuff ?

Comment: no. URL does not apply in this case. Only resources in bundle will be searched and applied.

Answer (score 1):

Supporting High-Resolution Screens

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW1

Comment: Link is now broken. Try: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're asking how to provide higher resolution images?

Use the same name, but append "@2x" to it. Then load it with `UIImage`'s `-imageNamed:` method to automatically load the correct version.

If your standard resolution image is 20x20 and is called Button.png, create a 40x40 image and call it Button@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

I make XIB file.
The resolution of XIB is not revokable in 320x480. 
The resolution wants to make me XIB of 640x960 for iPhone4.